# Image Handler not working with empty parameter in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, handler

I have tried to use default parameters, regex, and nothing works for the URL "/Assets/Images/".  I keep getting a 404 error saying it cant be found.  It works with just "/Assets/Images/0".

```
 routes.Add(
           "Images",
           new Route(
               "Assets/Images/{*Id}",
                   new ImageRouteHandler(new ImageHandler())
               )
           );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an action to AssetsController called Images

```
public class AssetsController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Images()
   {
      return View();
   }
   [HttpGet]
   public ActionResult Images(int id)
   {
      return View();
   }
}
```

Comment: But this is a HTTP Handler, not a Controller action.